# Wishlist qty update not working in a store view

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist

When I update the "qty" in the `wishlist` page 
the page reloads and set the default value to "1". When I input a value above "31" it works fine.

I had the same problem with cart qty update but I fixed it using this post : https://www.apptha.com/blog/how-to-bug-fix-shopping-cart-quantity-update-in-arabic-store-view-magento/

But I still have the issue in `wishlist` qty update.

The issue is only in Arabic store view.

```
Magento ver : 1.9.0.1
```

sorry for my bad formatting this is my first time posting in stack exchange !

Answer (score 0):

If this helps for the cart you can try to make the same for the wishlist. In **app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Controller/Abstract.php**, in `protected function _processLocalizedQty` please comment/remove this line (it should be line 56):

```
$qty = $this->_localFilter->filter((float)$qty);
```